# Safe methods of releasing/slaying trapped creatures

Tags: fallout-4

Background:

So during my first survival run on the newly released survival mode (XboxOne) I decided to try out the traps, in the hopes of netting some food. At the time I was around level 5 and could afford an insect trap.
Several hours later I open this trap expecting a radroach... I was attacked by a legendary bloodbug far above my level and due to hand opening the cage, I was in easy striking distance.

The main question here is:

> What are good, **safe** methods of releasing/slaying your trapped creatures when you are a low level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a [Beta Wave Emitter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Beta_wave_emitter) in the settlement that will cause all released creatures to be non hostile while the emitter is powered. Thus, you can release the critter, check how powerful it is, then proceed as required.

The beta wave emitter requires:

```
Copper (5)
Circuitry (3)
Aluminum (8)
Crystal (4)
Nuclear material (5)
Rubber (2)
```

The emitter also requires a rank in Animal Friend and one rank in Wasteland Whisperer to build. As such, unless you have 9 Charisma, you will be unable to build it until you do so.

My only other suggestion is to build walls and a roof around the exit and a load of turrets inside, then release the cage to the meat grinder.

Comment: What are the resource requirements? Due to early game (and survival) it may be difficult. I suppose it gives some usefulness to those perks

Comment: Copper (5)
Circuitry (3)
Aluminum (8)
Crystal (4)
Nuclear material (5)
Rubber (2) - Nothing too arduous, the only difficult thing might be Nuclear Material. However, there is a shack just south of Sanctuary that, if you do a bit of searching, will yield a decent haul of nuclear material.

Comment: I sem to be having issues finding crystal in my game; its really slowing down building radio beacons too

Comment: @nickson104 Don't have a good source of that, sorry. All I can recommend is tagging Crystal for search and picking up anything you find that has it.

Comment: I plan to, just need to get scrapper up. I will wait and see what other recommendations may come, then mark the answer.

Comment: @nickson104 You can mark without scrapper, a little Magnifying Glass icon will be next to the name of any item that contains the resource you're looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40610/discussion-between-nickson104-and-sgr).